# Program runs then says it has stopped working. Debugging issues

Tags: c

I am writing code in C using codeblocks that take a schedule and tells you if you are double booked on a certain item.

The file itself will be setup like:

```
2
2
0 1 5
1 8 12
```

where the 1st number is how many schedules there are and the second number is how many scheduled items are in that schedule.

The next few lines read `0` as Sunday, `1` as Monday and so forth and then the hours that day the schedule is full, start time to end time.

My code is:

```
//10/14/11
//This Code functions to let the user know if schedule conflicts exist in a certain amount of schedules.

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int Hours_week[168];
    int Num_schedules;
    int Num_items;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int w;
    FILE* ifp;
    int day;
    int start;
    int end;
    int Schedule;
    int booked;
    int index;

      //initialize the array by setting each spot equal to zero.
    for (w=0; w<168; w++){
        Hours_week[w] = 0;
    }

    //read in the file schedule.txt
    ifp = fopen("schedule.txt","r");

    //Read in the number of schedules
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &Num_schedules);

    //create a loop to run as many times as there are schedules.
    for (i=0; i<Num_schedules; i++){

        //read in the number of items in schedule.
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &Num_items);

        j = 0;
        while (j < Num_items){
            j++;

            //read in the day, start time, and end time.
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", day);
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", start);
            fscanf(ifp, "%d", end);

            //Multiply day by 24 and then add start and end hours to get their new times.
            start = (day * 24) + start;
            end = (day * 24) + end;

            for (k = start; k <= end; k++){
                if (Hours_week[k] == 0)
                    Hours_week[k] = 1;
                else if (Hours_week[k] == 1)
                    Schedule = booked;
            }

            //close the file
            fclose(ifp);


        if (Schedule == booked)
            printf("I'm sorry, schedule %d has a conflict in it.\n", i);
        else
            printf("Great Planning! You have no schedule conflicts in schedule %d.\n", i);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that debugging is far easier if you also include a sample run of the program in the question.

Comment: Turn your compiler's warning options up to 11 and keep them there until you know which ones you can disable and why it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 5):

You miss address-of operator here

```
         //read in the day, start time, and end time.
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", day);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", start);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", end);
```

correct should be

```
         //read in the day, start time, and end time.
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &day);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &start);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &end);
```

it's strange it's correct above! Time to go to sleep, for me at least!

Answer (score 0):

Because this reads a lot like homework, I'm going to be giving *hints* about the problems, rather than anything approaching *fixes* -- a huge part of learning is fighting the fight, but there's nothing fun about being stuck for hours at a time.

```
int Schedule;
int booked;
/* ... */
            else if (Hours_week[k] == 1)
                Schedule = booked;
/* ... */
    if (Schedule == booked)
        printf("I'm sorry, schedule %d has a conflict in it.\n", i);
```

You have used `booked` without initializing it first. (Any reasonable compiler should have *warned* about this -- please do not disregard your compiler warnings. Not all warnings need to be silenced, but the authors of your compiler are *very* good programmers and will warn you when things don't look right.)

```
        //read in the day, start time, and end time.
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", day);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", start);
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", end);
```

You've passed the (probably uninitialized) values of `day`, `start`, and `end` as *addresses* to `fscanf(3)`. Again, this is a case that your compiler should have warned you about. Don't ignore the warnings. :)

```
    j = 0;
    while (j < Num_items){
        j++;
```

This code is ripe for replacement with a `for` loop. Don't just use a different loop type for variety. `while` loops are *fine*, and if you were doing anything remotely interesting with `j` inside the loop, this might be fine. But you're simply incrementing it. Stick to the boring old idioms where you can, it'll make reading code far easier. (It comes with practice.) There's nothing *wrong* with this, it is just that I wondered why you chose a different loop construct here than all the other loops when it looked fundamentally identical.